# receiving error when making php curl soap request

Tags: php, xml, web-services, curl, soap

Receiving error:

a:InternalServiceFaultNo matching MessageFilter was found for the given Message.No matching MessageFilter was found for the given Message. at System.ServiceModel.Routing.MessageRpc.RouteToSingleEndpoint[TContract](RoutingConfiguration routingConfig)
 at System.ServiceModel.Routing.ProcessRequestAsyncResult`1..ctor(RoutingService service, Message message, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
 at System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService.BeginProcessRequest[TContract](Message message, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
 at System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService.System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter.BeginProcessRequest(Message message, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
 at AsyncInvokeBeginBeginProcessRequest(Object , Object[] , AsyncCallback , Object )
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.AsyncMethodInvoker.InvokeBegin(Object instance, Object[] inputs, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)System.InvalidOperationException

Code that is trying to make a soap/xml curl request:

```
$url = "https://domain.com/catalog";

    $soap_do = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,            $url );
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10);
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );            
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $xmlRequest); 
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE); 
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml", "SOAPAction: \"/soap/action/query\"", "Content-length: ".strlen($xmlRequest))); 

    $result = curl_exec($soap_do);

    print_r($result);
```

This is my first attempt at using soap and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The xml in the $xmlRequest variable is straight from the documentation provided with the three parts I needed to pass specific account details in, as seen below:

```
$xmlRequest = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="https://domain.com/Gateway.svc/Catalog/2012/12" xmlns:ns1="https://domain.com/Gateway.svc/Catalog/2012/12">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:GetItemsBySourceCode>
         <ns:catalogSourceCodeItemsRequest>
            <ns1:Header>
               <ns1:AccountAuth>
                  <!--Provide Service Credentials -->
                  <ns1:AccountId>accountid</ns1:AccountId>
                  <ns1:Password>password</ns1:Password>
               </ns1:AccountAuth>
               <ns1:Application>
                  <ns1:ApplicationIdentifier/>
                  <ns1:ClientIdentifier/>
                  <ns1:ProgramIdentifier/>
               </ns1:Application>
               <ns1:Parms>
                  <ns1:Parm>
                     <ns1:Name/>
                     <ns1:Value/>
                  </ns1:Parm>
               </ns1:Parms>
               <!--Not Required -->
               <ns1:TransactionId/>
            </ns1:Header>
            <!--Optional End Date for Catalog Data Pull-->
            <ns1:endDate/>
            <ns1:sourceCode>SourceCodeHere</ns1:sourceCode>
            <!--Optional Starting Date for Catalog Data Pull -->
            <ns1:startDate/>
         </ns:catalogSourceCodeItemsRequest>
      </ns:GetItemsBySourceCode>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';
```

Comment: y not use the soap lib?

Comment: Please contact the service-provider of `$url` and discuss the issue. The error message looks like on their end. For the code on your end you need to share with your question what specifically you want to ask about.